# UIScrollView Save/Restore Settings

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift4, multipeer-connectivity

I am using a UIScrollView in a MultiPeer setup.

The main application transmits the image that is placed inside the Scroll View (via a UIImageView) to the peers and they update their scroll views appropriately.

The image will always be the same image with the content changed slightly.

The peer may pan around the image, zoom in/out.

When the main application sends an update to the image, the peer is notified that an update has occurred.

However I want the peer's UIScrollView to retain its zoom and position values unless they have chosen to reset to the new image centre when the image arrives.

Any ideas on how one would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In your peers save the value of current zoom scale and x and y coordinates.
On notification of change of image, reload the view, load the image and apply these changes

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: savedX, y: savedY)
scrollView.setZoomScale(scale: savedZoomScale, animated: false)
```

Comment: Okay. So I have been only refreshing the image and then trying to restore the information. Is there any way to do it this way?